# LinkedList queue and thread safety

Tags: java, android, multithreading, collections

I have one thread that `add()`s objects into a LinkedList queue, and another thread that `poll()`s the queue for objects to process. These re the only two methods I use on my queue. I never iterate through the queue, nor add nor remove objects in the middle of the list. I cannot think of a scenario when the two threads step on each other and corrupt the data somehow, but perhaps my imagination is simply lacking.

The pushing is infrequent (several times per second) but the polling is very frequent (a couple thousand times per second). I wonder how much of a penalty I get for synchronizing the `add()` and the `poll()`. This is running on Android.

**Edit:** I am not looking for a `BlockingQueue`; I am blocking on I/O, not on objects in the queue:

The `run()` method on the polling thread blocks waiting for space to become available in an output buffer. When space becomes available, it looks to see if it has any objects waiting on the queue. If one is available, it serializes it into the output buffer. If the queue is empty (i.e. `poll()` returns `null`), it `poll()`s other, lower-priority queues, and if all are empty, serializes a "no data available now" message.

Comment: Does it matter what the overhead is? You have two threads competing for access to the same resource: you **need** synchronization. For what it's worth it's usually not that bad.

Comment: Why are you even polling at all? Can you send a 'message' directly to the other thread (with the new object) instead? Checkout Loopers and Handlers for implementation details

Comment: Thank you for the Looper suggestion. I have little experience with Android-specific libraries--thank you for bringing this one to my attention. I can see that working, sort of. The receiving thread cannot process objects immediately as it receives them--it blocks on an IO write. To make this work, I need a local copy of the queue in the receiving thread. Come to think if it, I'm not sure this is possible at all--from what I understand, Loopers block on their message queue, and I need to block on my IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without synchronization, you may get the case where the reading thread is polling the an object that has JUST been added to the queue, and that the list has not quite finished exiting out of the add() method.

If you look into the source, it's possible to screw something up with "expectedModCount = l.modCount;" because the latch for the poll is based on a line below it before modCount is actually modified.

Essentially, your remove is happening at the perfect time, probably with 1 element, while adding another at the same time, and getting something wrong.

To prevent this, you can wrap your accesses in synchronized(lst){} blocks or you can use the concurrent classes. I would prefer the concurrent queues because poll doesn't have to spin -- you can have a blocking take().

You're probably looking for: java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<String> que = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(100);
    que.add("");
    que.take();
```

Comment: Thank you for the failure scenario. I am adding synchronization to my code. The BlokingQueue is a neat solution to a different problem. I edit my original question to explain that I'm blocking on IO rather than the queue.

Answer (score 5):

Umn doesn't android have [BlockingQueues](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)? They are designed for exactly that scenario, no idea why you'd want to use anything else - can't get much more efficient..

Comment: Yes, Android has `java.util.concurrent` and stuff like `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Highly recommended for this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I see that my original question is unclear that I'm blocking on IO rather than data availability. I edit the question to elaborate on this.

Comment: @iter Your scenario doesn't stop you from using BlockingQueues. You can obviously implement the synchronization yourself (BlockingQueues as Lists or Arrays are rather trivial to implement), but you can just as well use the `poll()` method existing for both the LinkedList and the Array implementation. Or you can use `Collections.synchronizedList` and co - if I had to guess all three variants (self implementation included) should be basically identical from a performance point of view.